# Notifications settings in Github

Tags: github

I have an issue with Github notifications, I don't receive issues / pull requests in my own public repositories, it is quite annoying.

My settings in settings > notifications:

- Automatically watch teams
- Participating ( web, email )
- Comments on Issues and Pull Requests
- Pull Request pushes

When I try to add Watching, I now receive all update of a lot of repo, not good.

How should I simply receive important notifications in github ? 
  - Comments made after a issue / PR I submitted in another repo
  - Issue / PR made by contributors in my own repos

Comment: I tackle this at the email level rather than at the Github notification level - I just filter away any emails to `subscribed@github.com` and allow emails from Github directly To/CCing me to go to my Inbox.

Comment: this is a good workaround. But I'm just amazed that github doesn't support what I think is the main case...

Answer (score 0):

Github has a decent native notification service, have you made sure to configure the webhook as well as setting your notification preferences?

You need to go in to **Settings** for the repo for which you'd like to be notified, then **Webhooks**, then select your application type: either *JSON* or *www-form-urlencoded*, then test connectivity, and you should be up and running from there.

Honestly, Github's native notifications are a bit lacking so Axibase designed a tool which enhances them via programmatic integration. You'll receive detailed notifications to email, or some messenger service of your choice like Telegram or Slack. The underlying process is here for the Watch event:

[image]

This is just one of the options, keep in mind, you can be notified for new watches, new pushes, new forks, new projects, just about everything for which you can be notified from Github.

From the Linux terminal, you launch ATSD (the database which supports all the data processing and storage tasks) which generates a webhook. You copy and paste the webhook into the **Payload URL** field, where your email would go, configure the webhook, and that's about it. The whole setup is around ten minutes. The complete procedure is [here](https://axibase.com/use-cases/integrations/github/watch-notification.html) and has quick-launch and custom launch configurations. The quick-launch setup is configured for Slack.

Disclaimer: I work for [Axibase](https://axibase.com/).

Comment: Yeah, that's the way Github has it configured. The above user's workaround is good but still it is just that, a workaround. If you want the optimal functionality you'll have to play by their rules. With the sandbox solution here for example, you can add `--env` variables for all of the rules at once and use the same webhook for each repo. Shouldn't really add much time unless you're subbed to a ton of projects.